# MySQL in R: using sqldf and RLIKE

Tags: mysql, r, sqldf, rlike

I am trying to run a huge boolean sqldf in for a local dataframe in R like so:

```
sqldf("UPDATE df SET STORE_FLAG = 1
WHERE CONTENTS RLIKE '(([[:<:]]store[[:>:]]))'", drv='SQLite')
```

Query abbreviated above. The actual query is 20 words long with near functions

However, I have a syntax error using the RLIKE function:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
error in statement: near "RLIKE": syntax error
```

Is there a way to use RLIKE with the sqldf library?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered just using native R structures (or better yet `data.table`) instead of SQLite? What's the size/structure of the data?

Comment: @arvi1000 Data is around 300,00 rows with about 8 variables. I haven't considered data.table because replicating the sql query seems more difficult with lots of near functions. But maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Oh yeah, piece of cake for `data.table` size-wise. I'm not familiar with the exact specs of `near`, but I'd be shocked if there weren't a way to replicate it in R. Might be worth a new post about that

Comment: The `drv=` argument in the question is specifying that sqlite is to be used so that is what it is using, not MySQL.